# EE2 Embedded Template with Playa fields

Tags: expressionengine

Hopefully this is has a simple solution. I am pretty sure I am close. So here goes...

Code first.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="client" url_title="{embed:client_name}"}              
    <tr>
    {exp:playa:parents channel="project"}
    <td>
        {proj_name}
    </td>
    <td>
    {proj_job_number} 
        {job_number}
    {/proj_job_number}
    </td>
    <td>
        {entry_date format="%m/%d/%Y"}
    </td>   
    <td>
    {proj_producer} 
        {producer_name}
    {/proj_producer}
    </td>
    <td>
    {proj_vendor}
        {vendor_name}
    {/proj_vendor}
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="{proj_folder_zip}"><i class="icon-download"></i></a>
    </td>
    {/exp:playa:parents}
    </tr>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This is the code from the embedded template I am using. I am trying to return each Project channel entry along with the other playa field values from the project channel entry. I am able to return the results correctly however I am trying to format returned values into a html table. So finally my question is... What do I need to do as far as markup/tagging/conditionals so I can have one Project channel entry display per html table row. Right now all entries to the playa field display in one table cell ending up with one row with all the table cells in it. I can post more code if needed and or clarify anything I am missing. Any help on this issue is much appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: It was a simple solution. The table row tags needed to be included inside of the playa field tag pair. So if anyone ever needs to display tabular data using playa hope this helps!

Answer (score 7):

You need to place the `<tr>` tags *inside* the `{exp:playa:parents}` tag pair.